# Using string from method globally

Tags: c#, .net

Could someone give me a example if I wanted to use a string from a method
throughout my program? I would like to be able to use the fullName value in other parts
of my program.

Confused..

I guess I still don't understand how to call it correctly because I am getting FullNameNotinitialized.

```
 public class FindFile
        {
            public static string fullName;
            public static string FullName
            {
                get 
                {
                    if (fullName == null)
                         throw new FullNameNotInitialized();
                    return fullName;  
                }
                set 
                { 
                    fullName = value; 
                }
            }



            public class FullNameNotInitialized : Exception
            {
                public FullNameNotInitialized()
                    : base() { }

                public FullNameNotInitialized(string message)
                    : base(message) { }

                public FullNameNotInitialized(string format, params object[] args)
                    : base(string.Format(format, args)) { }

                public FullNameNotInitialized(string message, Exception innerException)
                    : base(message, innerException) { }

                public FullNameNotInitialized(string format, Exception innerException, params object[] args)
                    : base(string.Format(format, args), innerException) { }

            }
        public void sourceFinder()
        {

            string partialName = "APP";

            DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(@"/");

            FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + partialName + "*.*");

            foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
            {
                string fullName = foundFile.FullName;


                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fullName);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(fullName);


        }
        public void show()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fullName);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Taking fullName as static may help you.

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Comment: if you have multiple search results then what you expect as the output?

Comment: If you make your class, method and property names uppercase (as is traditional) it will be easier to spot that your `fullName` property is referring to itself instead of to a backing field. So you'll get a stack overflow when you call it. You can just use an automatic property: `public string FullName { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the variable of the same name in the `sourceFinder()` method. Ensure you are correctly using the field, property, and variable. Further, are you sure you want this to be static?

```
public class FindFile
{
    public static string _fullName;
    public static string FullName
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_fullName == null)
                 throw new FullNameNotInitialized();
            return _fullName;  
        }
        set 
        { 
            _fullName = value; 
        }
    }

    public void sourceFinder()
    {
        string partialName = "APP";

        DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(@"/");
        FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + partialName + "*.*");

        foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
        {
            // Do not use a variable here, use the field
            _fullName = foundFile.FullName;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fullName);
        }

        // Use the property...
        MessageBox.Show(FullName);
        // ... or the field
        MessageBox.Show(_fullName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a public class and access that throughout your application:

```
public class Application
{
    public string FullName
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

Then call this from your application:

```
Application.FullName;
```

Comment: I attempted to call it but got error that It could not be used like method.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make that `FullName` a static property. Please note that you should write names of classes and properties with camel case

```
    class FindFile
    {
        private static string fullName;
        public static string FullName
        {
            get 
            {
                return fullName; 
            }
            set 
            { 
                fullName = value; 
            }
        }
```

or

```
public static string FullName {get;set;}
```

but then you may access it even if it is not initialized, in that case, make your custom Exception and throw it if the `fullName` is `null`.

```
        class FindFile
        {
            private static string fullName;
            public static string FullName
            {
                get 
                {
                    if (fullName == null)
                         throw new FullNameNotInitialized();
                    return fullName;  
                }
                set 
                { 
                    fullName = value; 
                }
            }



public class FullNameNotInitialized : Exception
{
public FullNameNotInitialized()
: base() { }

public FullNameNotInitialized(string message)
    : base(message) { }

public FullNameNotInitialized(string format, params object[] args)
    : base(string.Format(format, args)) { }

public FullNameNotInitialized(string message, Exception innerException)
    : base(message, innerException) { }

public FullNameNotInitialized(string format, Exception innerException, params object[] args)
    : base(string.Format(format, args), innerException) { }

protected FullNameNotInitialized(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    : base(info, context) { }
```

}

So if you are getting those exceptions within your app, you should change the logic since you are accessing that value before it is initialized by calling method `sourceFinder()`

Comment: I updated code but getting IOexception now so I am not calling it correctly I suppose?

Comment: You never set the fullName, you are making a local value, change that, also, you can have only one value available globally while you are setting the fileName multiple times, do you need a list maybe?

Comment: well actually I have a cab file that the filename will change. So program intentions are to search root of device for MYAPP- and run that by just using a partial name. So my next step would be calling wceload to fire off the install by using the fullname value.

Comment: you have this line string fullName = foundFile.FullName; that creates the local value. You should change remove the string declaration. But I don't clearly see why do you need that fileName globally available

Comment: you are right i really won't need it globally. I can have everything
In the SourceFinder class. Seems to be working now, appreciate it much.